# MySql AutoIncrement causes slow MySQL connection

Tags: mysql, ms-access

This may be an open-ended question, which could have many answers, but I will ask anyway...

I am in process of moving over MySql databases to AWS while developing a new web app. I try to keep the current MySQL PROD updated every time I change something in the DEV AWS system now. So when I sync the DEV with PROD weekly, table structures are all consistent. 
I am also using Sequelize NodeJs package, which by default, is best when it works with ID fields when hooking to other tables/models. And I would rather avoid writing the SQL query statements. Therefore I needed to create an ID field on an existing table, rather than previous Primary Keys, which included 3 columns. When I add the ID column and assign it as the Primary and AI and remove the other 3 columns as not primary, the server opens up very slowly in MS Access, which is what the current company is using while I develop the Web application and slowly move away from current database.

Why would my actions cause this slowness? And how can I fix the issue of having the ID field as an AI field, but not cause MySQL to open up slow. I have verified this is what's causing this by undoing what I did and then MS Access can connect to db in 1-2 minutes.
Apparently when MS Access starts and finally connects to MySQL, everything runs fine after, it is the initial connection that takes around 15 minutes where before it was taking 1-2 minutes.

I have done a lot of research focusing more on MS Access configurations and MySQL configurations with no luck rather than maybe focusing on what I did that could have caused this. In which, I do not quite understand.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you do a link table in Access one of the steps is to "Select Unique Record Identifier". I wonder if it's still trying to uniquely identify based on those three columns. Since you changed the primary key, the indexes on your table may have switched. Can you create a new index on your mysql table to have those three columns, or update your linked table in access to use the ID to uniquely identify a record?

Comment: I will try that and let you know thanks.

Comment: @JNevill I put the primary key as the ID field I added and the rest of the previous primary keys as Indexes. That did it :) Thank you so much!

Comment: @ComputerVersteher yes that was my problem which JNevill mentioned as the solution. The 3 fields should have been added as indexes. Thank you for your comment :)

Comment: That's great to hear! I'm very glad that did the trick.